# Unable to read dictionary values in Django template

Tags: python, django, dictionary

I have a dictionary that I pass to Django template.

If I render just a dictionary with `{{dict}}` , then it is rendered fine, like this:

[image: dictionary]

If I render just the keys with `{{appoint}}`, they are also rendered just fine, like this:

[image: keys]

But if I render dictionary values with `{{dict.appoint}}` then I get nothing

[image: nothing]

I have read every post here about Django, template language and dictionaries and have not been able to solve this seemingly simple problem.

Answer (score 0):

Render your dict in html like this:

```
{% for key, value in dict.items() %}
<tr>
    <td> {{ key }}: </td> <td> {{ value }} </td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: But can't I just access any arbitrary value in the dictionary having the key?

Answer (score 0):

you can do with a custom template tag, check in here how to do it https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-template-tags/